# Switch window app by command line

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

"Alt+Tab" is used to switch a windows app to foreground, does anyone know how to do it with command line? or any API?

Comment: see this similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257587/bring-a-window-to-the-front-in-wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out KeyStuff: http://www.richpasco.org/utilities/keystuff.html

It's a pretty handy command line utility for issuing various keyboard commands to Windows. I haven't tested it extensively, but entering the Alt-Tab command works for me.