# Page in WPF losing focus

Tags: wpf

I have a Page in WPF which has a text box. This text box is set to be focused on load.

There is an application running in the background which takes a string value of a biometrics scan result and places it in that text box. This is a 3rd party application, and we have been told that it looks for a text box with a certain name, in an application with a certain name and if that text box is focused on, it will write that string in.

This works perfectly fine, but below is the problem I am having.

We have another piece of software which is a custom on screen keyboard. The text box can also be written into so the user can click a button to bring up this keyboard then start typing. However when this keyboard comes up, it seems to lose focus to my application and it doesnt come back again. For the lifecycle of our application running, the biometrics doesn't work because it doesn't see my application as the one currently in focus.

How do I force my application to come back in focus, but only when I want it to. I don't want it ALWAYS to be in focus and on the top, else the custom keyboard would never show.

I looked into Application.Activated Event with no joy, and even tried the following

`public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);`

Getting a but stuck, does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Could you try something like http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Activate() and Focus() methods?
This thread has a bunch of answers on topic [Bring a window to the front in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257587/bring-a-window-to-the-front-in-wpf)

This particular one worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/7559766/305020

Comment: I came across that thread but I am using a Page, not Window so there is no Activate or Focus methods (that I can see)

Comment: But where is your page located? As I understand, pages can't just float around desktop.