# Open Window Activate not working with button inside menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a really strange behaviour, and I hope someone can help me out.

I have the following XAML layout:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Menu>
        <Menu.Items>
            <MenuItem Padding="2,0,2,0">
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <Button Content="Details"
                            Click="Details_Click" />
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu.Items>
    </Menu>
    <Button Content="Details"
            Click="Details_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

Please notice that both buttons have the same Event registered.
The `Details_Click` Event looks like this:

```
private void Details_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewer = new DictionaryViewer();
    viewer.ShowActivated = true;
    viewer.Show();
    viewer.Topmost = true;
    viewer.Topmost = false;
    viewer.Activate();
    viewer.Focus();
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}
```

Now I am facing the problem, even with all the code from above the Window doesnt show up activated when I press the button inside the `Menu` but outside of it works with just `.Activate();`.
(How I know that window isnt activated: need 2 clicks to close/minimize/maximize it)

Why would my XAML Layout ruin the Activation of the `DictionaryViewer();` window, with the button **inside** `Menu`?

(To your information the DictionaryViewer is totally empty, its a fresh window nothing implemented yet)

**Edit:**

Yes, I know there is the `MenuItem_Click` Event that may make it work, but I need/want the button inside the Menu how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why are you making topmost true than false?

Comment: I think the menu handles some events and gets the focus after the MenuItem was clicked

Comment: @MichalCiechan got it from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4831839/2598770, since I am searching some time now and wondered why its not working and since 5 minutes when I moved button outside the menu i am in WTF mode...

Comment: @verdesrobert How would you fix that?

Comment: I think you shouldn't handle Button.Click inside menu but use Menu events to decide behaviour

Comment: @verdesrobert And since I want a button inside my Menu there is no way I can fix it?

Comment: You can have the button but try to handle the Menu Click and not the Button Click

Comment: @verdesrobert viewer.Activate(); should bring it to the foreground.

Comment: Still if the Activate is called after the lines of code are executed it may go in an event like for example MouseUp or who knows what events are internally handled by Menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe reason this is happening is because the Button inside the MenuItem is gaining Focus after the Window has opened.

If you set the Focusable property of the button inside MenuItem, this fixes the issue.

E.g.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Menu>
        <Menu.Items>
            <MenuItem Padding="2,0,2,0">
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <Button Content="Details"
                            Click="Details_Click"
                            Focusable="False" />
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu.Items>
    </Menu>
    <Button Content="Details"
            Click="Details_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I have a similar issue and am not understanding why if a menu item in the window is being focused on the window would not appear in the foreground? Also, the issue seems to be random in that sometimes the app/window will appear in the foreground and other times it will appear behind other windows...

Comment: @m4gik ask a question and point to it, I will try to take a look